# Как защитить скрипт от подмены

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Есть сервер на Node.js и клиент к нему.
Как определить, что на клиенте установлен тот самый скрипт, который передается с сервера, а не был подменен на какой-то другой?
Передача данных между клиентом и сервером происходит через socket.io

Comment: Если имеется в виду защита от преднамеренной подмены, то, в общем случае, никак. Всегда найдётся путь для обмана. А если доверяете клиенту и подмена может быть непреднамеренной, то можно посчитать хзш-сумму скрипта.

Comment: @kff, надо как раз защиту от преднамеренной подмены, просто на сервер и можно отправить и подмененную сумму....

Comment: Опишите чуть подробнее сценарий? Какой именно подделки вы опасаетесь? Задействованы ли какие-то третьи сервисы, или только ваш сервер + клиент?

Comment: @Sergiks а это сайт на laravel 5. Сам скрипт для бота.Сайт рулетка для стим предметов, надо предотвратить возможность обращения к методам бота, чтобы невозможно было отправить не тот трейд оффер

Comment: Логику не перенести целиком на сервер?

Comment: @Sergiks нет, увы не получится, слишком большие трудозатраты, не целесообразно

Comment: @Sergiks, Я себе представлял это так: проверяется на подлинность метода, который отправил данные на сервер, но я не могу придумать как это можно реализовать

Comment: Никак. Если вы отправили клиенту код, способный генерировать валидные сообщения, вы сами вручили ему все нужные инструменты для их подделки.

Comment: В чьих руках процессор – тот и в состоянии подменить любые данные. Критичный к подделкам код исполняйте на сервере.

Comment: @Sergiks, спасибо, учту

Answer (score 2):

Есть `integrity` атрибут.

Если браузер встречает тег `<link>` или `<script>`, то перед тем, как его выполнить, браузер сверяет хеш файла с `integrity` атрибута, и если они не совпадают, то отказывается выполнять скрипт.

Пример с бутстрапом:

```
<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Атрибут новый, а сам стандарт еще в статусе черновика, но в некоторых браузерах уже поддерживается.

Не очень понятно, что означает «Передача данных между клиентом и сервером происходит через socket.io». Если у вас этот скрипт передается через вебсокет, то принцип тот же, проверяйте хеш скрипта на клиенте, для этого есть весьма полезная библиотека: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

Comment: Можно намеренно пользоваться клиентом, не соблюдающим `integrity`. В данной модели угрозы считаем юзера злоумышленником, а он такое может.

Comment: В этом случае, убеждаться в том, что скрипт на клиенте тот же самый, нет никакой нужды, потому что даже если бы такой способ и существовал, все равно клиент может провести анализ сетевых запросов и ответов и восстановить протокол (а на практике, он будет еще и иметь доступ к исходному коду этого скрипта).
Вам нужно комплексное решение для обеспечения безопасности на сервере, или, как минимум, только для критичных запросов.

Comment: Именно! Поэтому ответ: **никак**.